# Force text in the child div fit into parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fittextjs

I have two div tags in my HTML code like this

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <p class="child-text"> ..... </p>
        <a class="child-link"> ..... </a>
        <p class="child-text"> ..... </p>
    </div>
</div>

#parent{ height: 400px; width:100px}
```

How can force the content of `#child` div **vertically** fit into the parent div ? 
I am looking for some thing that can take child div ID and resize its content dynamically. I have worked with `jQuery.fittext`. However, it get the `child-text` class id instead of `child` div id. In other words, it is not intelligent enough to identify what is in the `child` div and then rescale them.

Is there any other alternative for this ?

Comment: are you saying resize the .child so it fills the parent?

Comment: resize content of #child which is essentially .child-text and .child-link.

Comment: resize it so it fills #parent?

Comment: @ImagineWebDesign, yes, I have just add a missing CSS. right now the text fit horizontally in #parent but overflow vertically. This is a problem on Tablet browser. It is Ok on regular browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
var fontsize = 10;
while($('#child').height() <= $('#parent').height()){
    fontsize = fontsize +1;
    $('#child').css('font-size',fontsize+'px');
}
```

```css
#parent{ height: 400px; width:100px;background:red;}
#child{padding-bottom:5px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <p class="child-text"> Once upon a time </p>
        <a class="child-link"> there lived a monkey</a>
        <p class="child-text"> who loved to eat oranges </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

While `#child` height is less then `#parent` then it adds `1px` until it is not.  In the css, I gave `#child` a padding bottom of 5px, so it would not overflow

## <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19873qmm/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to scale `<img>` tags that might be in the `#child` as well?

Comment: $('#child img').css('height',fontsize+'px');

Answer (score 1):

Add a display **property value** of **table** to  **#parent** and **display property value** of **table-cell** to the elements you want to measure the height of **#parent**

```css
#parent, #child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  }

.child-link, .child-text { /* ID/Class of whatever element you want to measure the #parent */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  border-left: solid 5px white; /* Just for Division sake */
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"><p class="child-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sagittis felis nec est iaculis, id rhoncus eros efficitur. Aliquam justo felis, semper in placerat non, facilisis sed elit. </p>
      
      
        <a class="child-link"> Lorem </a>
        <p class="child-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sagittis felis nec est iaculis, id rhoncus eros efficitur. Aliquam justo felis, semper in placerat non, facilisis sed elit.
      
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sagittis felis nec est iaculis, id rhoncus eros efficitur. Aliquam justo felis, semper in placerat non, facilisis sed elit.
      
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sagittis felis nec est iaculis, id rhoncus eros efficitur. Aliquam justo felis, semper in placerat non, facilisis sed elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To make it dependent on the screen size, do something like below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { /* Adjust as needed */
enter code here

}
```

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for a interactive solution that can dynamically adjust text size based on the screen resolution.

Comment: Then start with @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {